# Loading data to a new table with row prefixes to reflect original source in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to clean and reconcile some datasets.

I have my original tables in raw format (all strings) and I am copying the information from the source, to another table I have created with the right data types.
However, I would like the new data in the new table to reflect the original source table in the form of (i.e.) 1_blablabla. So that, in the new table, I would have:
1_blablabla
2_blablabla
3_blablabla
and so on...

So far I am creating the new table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE *table_name*(
*column1_name* DATATYPE(XX),
*column2_name* DATATYPE(XX),
*column3_name* DATATYPE(XX),
*column4_name* DATATYPE(XX)
);
```

And then inserting the data from the old table with the raw data, to the new table with the "correct" format, like this:

```
INSERT INTO *new_table* (*column1_name*, *column2_name*, *column3_name*, *column4_name*)
SELECT (*sourcecolumn1*, *sourcecolumn2*, *sourcecolumn3*, *sourcecolumn4*)
FROM sourcetable1;
```

However, this loads the data as like for like, exactly as it is in the source table,
and instead, I would like it to reflect, at least in the rows of one of the columns, the prefix "1_" for example, so that it is intuitive to see where it came from.

Comment: I *assume* you are using SQL Server, not MySQL, as you state "SQL Server" in the question. Why do all your object names have asterisks around them? That isn't valid syntax.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. Which one are you asking about? Beyond that, the question is unclear . What is `1_blablabla`? A column name? Column value? In both cases that prefix is a *very* bad idea. Create separate columns and put any information you want there. Using prefixes means you won't be able to query your data without having to parse every single value every time. Indexes will be useless as they can only be used to find the actual value or range of values, not strings at the middle or the end

Comment: Maybe have an extra column in the target table that designates the source table of a record. Prefixing non string data isn't possible and even for string data it's nonsense.

Comment: Why not just add a `Source` column and populate that in your `insert`?

Comment: `it is intuitive to see where it came from.` the prefix is *counter*intuitive. Add extra columns with the metadata you want eg source table, or original row ID.

Comment: @Larnu, this is my first ever question here, so I was trying to make it italic in the editor box. Once I put the "```" to make it a code, I forgot to remove the * that make the quote italics. I will change it now. It is obviously not like that in the original code :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
very good suggestion! thank you! 
I will do that :) it makes way more sense!

Comment: @stickybit
likewise, very helpful! that makes way more sense :) I will do this

Comment: @Stu thank you :) I will do this!